# Python: Print to file until empty line?

Tags: python, if-statement, file-io, printing

I currently have:

```
for i in range (srange, erange):
    lines=open("%s\%s\propkaoutputfiles\propka_protein_output_%s%s.pka" %(filepath, name, aminoacid, i), "r")
    FILE=open("%s\%s\propkamanip\%sinpropka%s.txt" %(filepath, name, aminoacid, i), "w")
    for line in lines:
        if "0.00    0" and " B   7."in line and (line.split()[0]) == "%s" %aminoacid:
            print >> FILE, " %s in %s Structure %s" %(aminoacid, name, i)
            print >> FILE, line
        if "0.00    0" and " B   8."in line and (line.split()[0]) == "%s" %aminoacid:
            print >> FILE, " %s in %s Structure %s" %(aminoacid, name, i)
            print >> FILE, line
```

the data I am reading looks like this, so I would like to embed inside my "if in line" a code that will take that line if it meets that criteria and print the next lines in the document to my new file until an empty line is found:

LYS B    8.X  0.00    0

LYS B

LYS B

empty line here

ARG B    8.9  0.00

Python newb here, thanks!

Comment: Start with properly formatting the code in your question (the indentation is wrong).

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke sorry, done now, missed that part as I was trying to work out the formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
file1 = open("your input file", "r")
file2 = open("your output file", "w")

while True :
    line = file1.readline()
    if line :
        if "your criteria ..... " in line :
            file2.write("your header here\n")
            file2.write(line)
            line = file1.readline()
            while line and line != "\n" :
                file2.write(line)
                line = file1.readline()
    else :
        file1.close()
        file2.close()
        break
```